# Monitoring Kafka SSL Certs Validity

Tags: apache-kafka, ssl-certificate, monitoring, acl

Imagine you have a simple Kafka Cluster with 3 Brokers. You use the SSL Certs for client authentication and Kafka ACLs. Also the SSL is enabled for inter-broker communication. What would be the recommended way to Monitor the Validity/Expiration of the Certs used?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

For now, just have written a small Java app, that does the checks and retrieves the certificate expiring within given amount of days,  by scheduled calls of the following method, for each of the used JKS files:

```
List<X509Certificate> getCertificatesThatExpireWithin(final int minCertsValidityInDays, 
           final File keystoreFile,final String keyStorePassword) throws MyAppException {
            final List<X509Certificate> expiringCerts = new LinkedList<>();
            final java.util.Date maxDateTime = java.util.Date.from(java.time.LocalDate.now()
                    .plusDays(minCertsValidityInDays).atStartOfDay(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toInstant());
    
            try (final FileInputStream is = new FileInputStream(keystoreFile)) {
                final KeyStore keystore = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
                keystore.load(is, keyStorePassword.toCharArray());
                final Enumeration<String> keystoreAliases = keystore.aliases();
                while (keystoreAliases.hasMoreElements()) {
                    final String alias = keystoreAliases.nextElement();
                    final Certificate cert = keystore.getCertificate(alias);
                    if (cert instanceof X509Certificate) {
                        X509Certificate x509Cert = (X509Certificate) cert;
                        if (!x509Cert.getNotAfter().after(maxDateTime)) {
                            expiringCerts.add(x509Cert);
                        }
                    }
                }
            } catch (KeyStoreException | NoSuchAlgorithmException | CertificateException | IOException e) {
                LOGGER.error("Can not check the validity of the certificates in " + keystoreFile.getPath() + " due to", e);
                throw new MyAppException(
                        "Can not check the validity of the certificates in " + keystoreFile.getPath() + " due to", e);
            }
            return expiringCerts;
        }
```

Comment: is this working for you ? Have you deployed this in kubernetes pod ?

Comment: Sure. Had to write a small microservice, that runs in a POD on an Openshift Cluster, does a scheduled check of the certs validity every 24 hours, and sends an email, if the expiration period is less than a predefined threshold.